# I don't know anymore what to do in this c++

Tags: c++

Here's the code and the compilation error

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
double RTinSeries, RTinParallel, R1, R2, R3, R4, R5, R6, Option, Opt1, Opt2;
cout<<"Enter your option:(1 for parallel and 2 for series)";
cin>>Option;
if (Option =< 1 && Option >=3)
{
  cout<<"Error!";
  cout<<"You've enter a wrong Option";
}
{
  else if (Option = 1);
  for (Opt1=RTinParallel; RTinParallel = (1/((1/R1)+(1/R2)+(1/R3)+(1/R4)+                (1/R5)+(1/R6))););
  cout<<"Your Choice is Parallel";
  cout<<"Enter Resistance Value for R1:";
  cin>>R1;
  cout<<"Enter Resistance Value for R2:";
  cin>>R2;
  cout<<"Enter Resistance Value for R3:";
  cin>>R3;
  cout<<"Enter Resistance Value for R4:";
  cin>>R4;
  cout<<"Enter Resistance Value for R5:";
  cin>>R5;
  cout<<"Enter Resistance Value for R6:";
  cin>>R6;
  cout<<"Total Resistance in Parallel is:"<< Opt1<<"ohms"<<endl;
}
{
else (Option = 2);
for (Opt2=RTinSeries; RTinSeries = R1 + R2 + R3 + R4 + R5 + R6;)
  cout<<"Your Choice is Series";
  cout<<"Enter Resistance Value for R1:";
  cin>>R1;
  cout<<"Enter Resistance Value for R2:";
  cin>>R2;
  cout<<"Enter Resistance Value for R3:";
  cin>>R3;
  cout<<"Enter Resistance Value for R4:";
  cin>>R4;
  cout<<"Enter Resistance Value for R5:";
  cin>>R5;
  cout<<"Enter Resistance Value for R6:";
  cin>>R6;
  cout<<"Total Resistance in Series is:"<<Opt2<<"ohms"<<endl;
}

  system("pause");
  return 0;


}
```

And the compilation result

```
9:15: error: expected primary-expression before '<' token
15:7: error: 'else' without a previous 'if'
15:26: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]
16:92: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]
33:3: error: 'else' without a previous 'if'
34:63: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]
```

Comment: I would recommend reading up or taking a basic course in the fundamentals of C or C++. You have basic syntax errors that you should learn how to fix on your own.

Comment: `else if (Option = 1);` should be `else if (Option == 1);`. The first is an assignment the second is a test.

Comment: well i've already fix that but the error i've got right now is different

Comment: i've already fix that now i have another error 
error: expected primary-expression before ')' token

Comment: @JarrylAlmocera Read about the for-loop in your fine book. Then conclude that this is not an appropriate use for it. Also take a few minutes to read about what `=` means (it is not the same as `==`).

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Mostly what we like to hear is that you've had a go at fixing it yourself - and for that we'd like to hear what you've tried... and what the results were of that (even if it was just more errors). show us that you're not just dumping your code on us, but are really working hard at fixing it... and we'll be happy to help you with it.

Comment: *Please* look at the error messages, and the line number on which they occur.  You have a chronic misunderstanding of the format of if-else blocks.  When this finally compiles, you also have logical errors to deal with.

Comment: **Try something simpler.** We were all beginners once, but you can't learn anything if you attempt exercises too far beyond you ability. Try the simplest `if` block you can devise. When that works perfectly, try an `if-else`. Don't attempt to actually *do* anything (like calculate resistance) until you understand the tools.

Comment: Google `if else c++`: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_if_else_statement.htm

Answer (score 4):

You have a number of basic syntax errors. I'll list a few of them, but really, your task is:
1) read the very first error-message...
2) look up a C++ book (or google) about the keywords and expressions that you are using on that line...
3) look very carefully to see what is different about how you're doing it
4) use that to fix the problem in your code

For example:
`(Option =< 1 && Option >=3)`

If you look up the "less than or equal" and "greater than or equal" operations, you'll find that they are always `<=` and `>=` not `=<`
So, your expression should be:

`(Option <= 1 && Option >=3)`

Do you see the one char difference there?

For this one:

```
if (Option =< 1 && Option >=3)
{
  cout<<"Error!";
  cout<<"You've enter a wrong Option";
}
{
  else if (Option = 1);
```

If you read up on if/else you will see that the structure is always:

```
if (condition) 
{
   // stuff here
}
else if (condition2) 
{
   // more stuff here
}
```

have a look at how your curly braces look in your code.
they look very different.
curly braces should always surround the code-blocks and should begin with `{` and end with `}` - yours don't.You have a `}` immediately followed by a `{` and *then* have the else section... which is just all out of whack.

try making a copy of your code... and removing all the statements that do stuff... and *just* keep the if/elses and the curly brackets and see where they line up... lining up curly braces should be easy to do once the extra code is not there... and then you can add back the code statements